# Why adsense on Blogger doesn't show

Tags: blogger, google-adsense

I have a blog with Blogger. It's a fresh blog which have a bit users/visitors. I want to try Adsense by Google. But when I click Adsense link, Nothing happen, just blank page content.

[image]

I tried this on different browser, but nothing happen. Is there a bug? Or Google have a rule for blog which have most visitor? Or something like that?

Comment: What happens when you click the link on that page - does it explain it do you?

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to link your Blog with Adsense, you must have an established blog which has been running for several months already with dozens of posts which contain plenty of quality content apart from meeting all [requirements established by the program](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9724). The option to link with AdSense will automatically appear and take you to the set up process.

These options become available differently to people depending from which country they reside in. People from countries like India, due to the volume of applicants or other requirements, tend to wait more and as much as a year in order to get an AdSense account. If the option to link is not working, your blog simply does not qualify to be set up with AdSense through the monetization settings at this time. Google has also stated that even when it comes to payment handling, it is also something that affects [how they handle accounts](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/adsense/payments/5_U7EGUSH7w"). However, if you feel like you meet all the above and 6 months to a year have already gone by, your best option is to contact Google AdSense through [their support forum](https://productforums.google.com/d/forum/adsense).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can attach your Adsense to blogger blog and you can also enroll for an Adsense account on the behalf of your blogger blog. Eligibility to participate in Adsense is [You should meet eligibility requirements](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9724?hl=en). It also shows that site has been active for at least six months.
Wherever for Blogger and YouTube you won't be able to apply via regular application process, But You have to meet their policy to get your blog or channel approved for monetize. at least meet the following requirements:

- You have to be at least 18 year old.
- Your site should comply with their Program policies.
- You site should be active for six months at least.
  Before enrolling yourself for Adsense you should review your site first that you have contents, you have organic traffic, and your site meets Blogger Content Policy.
  And here is a way to [advertise your blog](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1269077?visit_id=1-636303296730757300-207199480&rd=1).